# Change color (of some of the text) in a Swing text area

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

Can I change foreground color in Java `JTextArea` for specific text? I want to change some words to red color and leave others in black.

Comment: You'll have to write a DocumentListener to do this.  [HowTo Use Text Areas](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html)

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc actually I think the OP needs a `JTextPane` and not a `JTextArea`

Comment: [How to use Editor Panes and Text Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html)

Comment: Just a question is JTextPane the same jEditorPane

Comment: *"is JTextPane the same jEditorPane"* the Java 'core APIs' have extensive documentation. Try putting the class name and API into a search engine and follow the link to Oracle. Much faster than asking on a forum.